# VueJS: как работать с html блоками?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
"complect" : [ 
    "iPhone", 
    "EarPods", 
    "Адаптер", 
    "Кабель",
    "Документация"
]
```

Нужно реализовать на VueJS CRUD данного элемента. Строк может быть сколько угодно.Один input - 1 эллемент массива. Или VueJS нет функций аналогичных в JQuery?

При Update у каждой строки должны быть кнопки обновления и удаления строки.

**Главный вопрос:** как работать с HTML элементами через VueJS?
Как создавать добавлять строки в конец эллемента?

Comment: Извиняюсь за прямоту - но вы читали документацию?

Comment: Да, и если я правильно вас понимаю вся ваша помощь заключается в том, чтобы отправить меня читать документацию - спасибо, премного благодарен.

Comment: Суть в том, что если бы вы хорошо читали доки, то поняли бы, что vue не используется для прямого манипулирования DOM, а создаётся шаблон, который связывается с данными. После jQuery эту парадигму возможно сложно понять, но забудьте про jQuery и перечитайте доки